# Why does WCF project keep loading into WCFTestClient?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf

In VS.NET 2013, I have a WCF project. It use to load in the web browser but for whatever reason, it now opens the WCFTestClient and loads there. How do I change this back to the web browser?

Answer (score 0):

WCF Test Client starts when you have .svc or .xamlx file open in Solution Explorer. Just open some other file before hitting F5.

Or it could be that you have WcfTestClient.exe specified in command line arguments in:
project properties -> Debug -> Start Options

If that is the case, just delete it from there.

Comment: Neither apply in this case.